# How to Change date format in line chart in Python to YYYY-MM only?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm newbie in Python. I have grouped an order using count aggregate by the Month like this :

```
df4 = (df2.groupby([df2['tanggal_permohonan'].dt.to_period('M').rename('tanggal')])
   ['no_agenda'].count().rename('jumlah').reset_index())
```

and it generated like what I want that grouped in YYYY-MM like this:

[image]

Then, I want to make a line chart using the columns, and I have tried like this

```
plt.plot(df5['month'], df5['jumlah'], color='red', marker='o')
plt.title('Unemployment Rate Vs month', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('month', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('jumlah', fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

But the result like this that is not order by year and the label in x-axis is only month so when August again the line will back again. I want it show like the table. Any solution?

[image]

Update : I have tried using date formatted in matplotlib like this :

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(df5.month, df5.jumlah, lw=2)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

But it show error like this

```
Error in callback <function install_repl_displayhook.<locals>.post_execute at 0x7fb18ce55710> (for post_execute):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in post_execute()
    107             def post_execute():
    108                 if matplotlib.is_interactive():
--> 109                     draw_all()
    110 
    111             # IPython >= 2

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in __call__(self, x, pos)
    608     def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
    609         if x == 0:
--> 610             raise ValueError('DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is '
    611                              'an illegal date; this usually occurs because '
    612                              'you have not informed the axis that it is '

ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date; this usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in __call__(self, x, pos)
    608     def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
    609         if x == 0:
--> 610             raise ValueError('DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is '
    611                              'an illegal date; this usually occurs because '
    612                              'you have not informed the axis that it is '

ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date; this usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()
<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your 'tanggal' column is of datetime type

```py
df4.dtypes
```

If it is not, convert it to datetime

```py
df4['tanggal'] = pd.to_datetime(df4['tanggal'])
```

Then, you could import DateFormatter from matplotlib to plot the axis as YYYY-mm numbers

```py
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

date_format = DateFormatter('%Y-%m')

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
... # your plot and plot configs go here as usual

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
```

Also, check if you're plotting the write dataframe (first you assigned a variable named df4, then you plotted df5, have a look at that).

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. You're right that the dtypes of 'tanggal' is int64. But when I try to change it it show error  TypeError: Passing PeriodDtype data is invalid. Use `data.to_timestamp()` instead after I tried to change to timestamp, it show new error : module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_timestamp'

Comment: your 'tanggal' column still has those values in the form '2021-11', '2021-10'... if so, they should be an object, not an int64. Try having a look at the names of your dataframes, maybe you're confusing one with another and thus getting this error.